# System service or disable uninstalling?

Tags: android, android-service

Is it possible to write an Android `Service` that cannot be erased/disabled/uninstalled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can modify the firmware to include your application, and such applications can only be removed by replacing the whole firmware.